# What bucket_count value should I use if I know the intended number of map keys?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, std, buckets

I'm creating an `std::unordered_map` which I will immediately proceed to populate with n key-value pairs - and I know n. After that no more elements will be added - I will only be performing lookups.

What, therefore, should I pass as `bucket_count` to the constructor?

**Notes:**

- I know it's not terribly critical and I could simply not specify anything and it will work.
- This is related to, but not a dupe of, [What should I pass to unordered_map's bucket count argument if I just want to specify a hash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179441/what-should-i-pass-to-unordered-maps-bucket-count-argument-if-i-just-want-to-sp?s=1%7C4.4892))
- If it helps your answer, you may assume I want to have a load factor between f_1 and f_2 (known in advance).
- I'm using the default hash function, and I don't know what the input is like, but it's unlikely to be adversarial to the hashing..

Comment: It very much depends on what you will do with this map afterwards. Will you add other elements, or just read it ? Do you seek speed or space efficiency ? How much collisions does you hash function yield on your set ? It is reasonable to think about the load factor rather than the actual number of buckets.

Comment: @Jean-BernardJansen: See edit. Also, I'd like some sort of a reasonable default - the same way we now have a reasonable default without knowing n. Adding that information, and applying the same considerations, should yield some number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) in 23.5.4.2  [unord.map.cnstr] (this is the final draft of C++14)
by default the `max_load_factor` for an `unordered_map` is 1.0, so you could just set the bucket_count to `n`.

There is obviously a space-time trade-off between increasing the bucket count for improved speed and decreasing it (and raising the max load factor) for improved space.

I would either not worry about it, or if it is a *large* map, set the bucket count to `n`.  Then you can worry about optimizing when profiling shows you have a problem.

If you know the range of load factors you want, then you just set the bucket count to `std::ceil(n/(std::max(f_1,f_2))`, (and set the load factor before you fill the map).

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact you have a range for your load factor, the only missing information is the collision rate. You can simply use `nb_buckets = n / f_2` and you will be sure to get a load factor less than or equal to `f_2`. Ensuring correctness about `f_1` requires data about the collision rate.