# Custom equality compartor in unordered_map with initialization parameters

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am using std::unordered_map with a custom equality comparator class like so:

```
class KeyCompare {
private:
    HelperClass* helper;

public:
    KeyCompare(HelperClass* helper): helper(helper) {}
    
    bool operator()(const Key& key1, const Key& key2) const {
        return helper->doStuff(key1, key2);
    }
}
```

At some point in my code I initialize my map like this:

```
HelperClass helper;
std::unordered_map<Key, Value, Hasher, KeyCompare> map;
```

I would like to pass `helper` to the map such that `KeyCompare` objects are created with this `helper`. Is such a thing possible? I can use some global variable if absolutely necessary, but I would really like to avoid that.

Comment: Pass them in [`std::unordered_map`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `KeyCompare` needs a helper it isn't default constructible. You must therefore supply an instance to the `unordered_map` when you construct it.

Example:

```
HelperClass helper;

std::unordered_map<Key, Value, Hasher, KeyCompare> map{
    1,                   // bucket count
    Hasher{},            // hasher instance
    KeyCompare{&helper}  // your KeyCompare with the helper
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/511ME36M5)

Comment: Question is then [which `bucket_count` to pass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179441/what-should-i-pass-to-unordered-maps-bucket-count-argument-if-i-just-want-to-sp).

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed. It seems passing any small number is usually ok?